# What hooks are needed to get CRAN binaries compiled using OpenMP? (on OS X)

Tags: r, macos, openmp, cran

When submitting a package to [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org), how can one get the resulting binaries for Windows and Mac OSX to take advantage of OpenMP?

i.e., what make or compiler hooks do the CRAN machines look for to build for OpenMP code?

Answer (score 2):

1. Unix source

   - R has good OpenMP support under unix. Just include the ifdef _OPENMP. (users must download package source and compile packages on their machine).
2. OS X binaries

   - Since mid-2018, R for OS X is compiled using clang, with a custom clang giving OpenMP support. Binary packages which take advantage of OpenMP (e.g. OpenMx) run in parallel. Source compilation is eased by the compiler installer provided at [CRAN tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/clang-6.0.0.pkg)https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/clang-6.0.0.pkg
   - Using other non-CRAN compilers (e.g. homebrew) is strongly advised against.
3. Windows binaries

   - As of 2019, the windows toolchain supports OpenMP and pthreads, but it's slow and not enabled by default. Comments indicate this might change.

#### Refs

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support

Answer (score 1):

As of R 3.5.3 manual:

> Apple builds of clang on macOS currently have no OpenMP support, but
>   CRAN binary packages are built with a clang-based toolchain which
>   supports OpenMP.
>   http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools gives some idea
>   of what compilers support what versions.

Source-based installs of CRAN packages for most MacOS users will fail and/or not have openmp, unless they have installed, e.g. via homebrew, clang with openmp support. The method for doing evolves, so search for recent posts with terms like "homebrew clang openmp makevars R CRAN".